# Bash. Work with diff

Tags: linux, bash, diff, ls

Write a script to compare files in two directories, ignoring the changes associated with the addition of blank lines, spaces, tabs, and also use wildcards in excludeFiles, to exclude from the comparison of unnecessary files. The file specified as a parameter, write down the names of these files, their i-node, and creation date.

I know how to do first part(before point).

```
   diff -rwBd -X excludeFiles mydir1 mydir2 > changes.diff
```

But don't understand how to do second part "The file specified as a parameter, write down the names of these files, their i-node, and creation date."?? I think i need to use ls....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ignore diff output (-q), get file names and use ls for inodes (-i) and ctime (-c)

```
$ diff -rwBdq -X excludeFiles mydir1 mydir2 | awk '{print $2" "$4}' | xargs ls -lic
2415432 -rw-r--r-- 1 user group  4163 Nov  6 15:21 mydir1/file1
2415434 -rw-r--r-- 1 user group  1042 Nov  6 15:21 mydir2/file1
2415433 -rw-r--r-- 1 user group  4163 Nov  6 15:21 mydir1/file2
2415435 -rw-r--r-- 1 user group  1042 Nov  6 15:21 mydir2/file2
```

Comment: http://ashok-linux-tips.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-get-file-creation-time-in-linux.html. In EXT2/3 getting creation time is not possible I think, but EXT4 it's. debugfs command using the inode#. ls -lic will change the time each time the file is changed

Comment: yes, you are right, but hopefully OP could use it as starting point, ctime is closest what we could get without additional information